# Create dataframe with timestamp field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, azure-databricks

On Databricks, the following code snippet

```
%python

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [F.current_timestamp()]
schema = StructType([StructField("current_timestamp", TimestampType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
display(df)
```

displays a table with value "null". I would expect to see the current timestamp there. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createDataFrame` does not accept PySpark expressions.

- You could pass python's `datetime.datetime.now()`:

  ```py
  import datetime

  df = spark.createDataFrame([(datetime.datetime.now(),)], ['ts'])
  ```

  Defining schema beforehand:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql.types import *
  import datetime

  data = [(datetime.datetime.now(),)]
  schema = StructType([StructField("current_timestamp", TimestampType(), True)])
  df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
  ```
- OR add timestamp column afterwards:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  df = spark.range(3)

  df1 = df.select(
      F.current_timestamp().alias('ts')
  )

  df2 = df.withColumn('ts', F.current_timestamp())
  ```